# How do I use a button to turn an LED on and off using python and a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to use a button to turn an LED on and off. I have used some sample code that I found online to turn the LED on, but only when the button is pressed down. I would like to run a script that detects when the button has been pressed and if the LED is on, it turns off. If the LED is off, it turns on.

I get the following error:

> TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Code:

```
btn_pin = 4
led_pin = 12
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(btn_pin, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(led_pin, GPIO.OUT)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(4) == 1:
        if GPIO.output(12) == LOW:
            GPIO.output(12, GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
            GPIO.output(12, GPIO.LOW)
main()
```

Comment: `GPIO.output` seems to require two outputs, but you're doing `GPIO.output(12)`, and only passing one.

Comment: `GPIO.output` doesn't return a value. What you can do is set a variable to whether it is on or off every time you change it and if you don't change it after that without updating the variable so you will know the state of it at a given time

Comment: You need to use `GPIO.input` to read the state of your output. Also, you will need to introduce some delay before testing again if the button is pressed, so that the user has time to release it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.IN) #button
GPIO.setup(21,GPIO.OUT) #led
while True:

    # Turn LED off
    print ("LED off")
    GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)

    # waiting for button press
    while GPIO.input(13) == 1:
        time.sleep(0.2) 

    # Turn LED on
    print ("LED on")
    GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)


    # waiting for button press
    while GPIO.input(13) == 1:
        time.sleep(0.2)

    print ("LED off")
    GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
```

Hope this code will help you. Cheers.